# count by condition after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'item':[200,200,201,333,333,334],
    'page':[1,1,2,3,2,2]
})
```

i want to convert df into df1 like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,2,2,2],
    'item':[200,201,333,333,334],
    'page':[1,2,3,2,2],
    'page1_cnt':[2,0,0,0,0]
})
```

Question: size if page == 1 of groupby

this is my way. can i get a more pythonic way?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'item':[200,200,201,333,333,334],
    'page':[1,1,2,3,2,2]
})

df['pageCnt'] = df.groupby(['id','item','page']).page.transform('size')
df['page1Cnt'] = np.where(df.groupby(['id','item']).page.apply(lambda x: x==1), df.pageCnt, 0)
```

Comment: do you want a column for each page or just the first page?

Comment: each page, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this one-liner, it creates a column 'page1_cnt' as a boolean True if equal to 1 and converts it to an integer using mul(1), then we groupby and sum the integer for page1_cnt:

```
df.assign(page1_cnt=df.page.eq(1).mul(1))\
  .groupby(['id','item','page'], as_index=False)['page1_cnt'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   id  item  page  page1_cnt
0   1   200     1          2
1   1   201     2          0
2   2   333     2          0
3   2   333     3          0
4   2   334     2          0
```

Or we can use set_index and sum with parameter level:

```
df.assign(page1_cnt=df.page.eq(1).mul(1))\
  .set_index(['id','item','page'])\
  .sum(level=[0,1,2]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id  item  page  page1_cnt
0   1   200     1          2
1   1   201     2          0
2   2   333     3          0
3   2   333     2          0
4   2   334     2          0
```

Comment: Scott Boston, great!

Answer (score 0):

The way to get pageCnt is neat :-) , I will use `where` to get the page1Cnt

```
df['page1Cnt']=df.pageCnt.where(df.page==1,0)
df
Out[700]: 
   id  item  page  pageCnt  page1Cnt
0   1   200     1        2         2
1   1   200     1        2         2
2   1   201     2        1         0
3   2   333     3        1         0
4   2   333     2        1         0
5   2   334     2        1         0
```

Without

```
df['pageCnt1'] = df.groupby(['id','item','page']).page.transform(lambda x : len(x) if len(x)>1 else 0)
df
Out[706]: 
   id  item  page  pageCnt1
0   1   200     1        2
1   1   200     1        2
2   1   201     2        0
3   2   333     3        0
4   2   333     2        0
5   2   334     2        0
```

Comment: @J.Doe add it :-)