# groupby is not functioning when working with multiple columns in numpy.where

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to add multiple columns to `numpy.where` `groupby` question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171017/using-pandas-groupby-and-numpy-where-together-in-python)

but got error when I add another column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Occupation':list('dddeee'),
         'Emp_Code':list('aabbcc'),
         'Gender':list('MFMFMF')
})

   Occupation   Emp_Code    Gender
0          d    a           M
1          d    a           F
2          d    b           M
3          e    b           F
4          e    c           M
5          e    c           F
```

by following @jezrael 's solution I just added `Emp_Code` to groupby

```
m = df['Gender'].eq('M')
df['new'] = np.where(m, m.groupby(df['Occupation','Emp_Code']).transform('mean').mul(100), 0)
print (df)
```

but got this error

> KeyError: ('Occupation', 'Emp_Code')

I could not figure out why this has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
m = df['Gender'].eq('M')
df['new'] = df.assign(mask=m).groupby(['Occupation', 'Emp_Code'])['mask'] \
              .transform('mean').mul(100)

df.loc[~m, 'new'] = 0
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Occupation Emp_Code Gender    new
0          d        a      M   50.0
1          d        a      F    0.0
2          d        b      M  100.0
3          e        b      F    0.0
4          e        c      M   50.0
5          e        c      F    0.0
```

**Update**

> Is it possible get one liner?

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['Gender'].eq('M'), df.assign(mask=df['Gender'].eq('M')).groupby(['Occupation', 'Emp_Code'])['mask'].transform('mean').mul(100), 0.)
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. Is it possible get one liner like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293173/count-by-condition-after-groupby-in-pandas